# I received error "bash: line 1: [: -ne: unary operator expected" after run the below script

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting

This script provides the expected output, but throw the error "bash: line 1: [: -ne: unary operator expected". Techies help to fix this.

```
#!/bin/bash
USR="root"

# Email
SUBJECT="NTP Service Status Report"
EMAIL="skrishna1@fmi.com"
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/ntp_status.txt"

# create new file
>$EMAILMESSAGE

# connect each host and pull up user listing
for host in `cat SAP_Prod_servers_51`
do
echo "--------------------------------" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "* HOST: $host " >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "--------------------------------" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
ssh $USR@$host "UP=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep ntpd | wc -l);
if [ "$UP" -ne 1 ];
then
        echo "NTP is down.";
        sudo service ntpd start

else
        echo "NTP Service is running.";
fi" >> $EMAILMESSAGE
done

# send an email using /bin/mail
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

Comment: You're missing a " on the **ssh** line: `ssh $USR@$host "UP=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep ntpd | wc -l)";`

Comment: ... and after the edit, you can *see* the missing quote in the coloring of the code.

Comment: @ajgringo619 the "missing" `"` appears to be after the `fi` a few lines down - presumably because the intention is to run the whole thing on the remote host (it wouldn't make sense to assign `UP` on the remote host then try to test it on the local host). Perhaps the outer `"` just need to be changed to `'`?

Comment: @steeldriver - that's very likely.

Comment: I tend to monitor service statuses with a Nagios plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

The base problem is that the command being sent over `ssh` is in double-quotes, so the `$( ... )` and `$UP` are being expanded by the local shell before the command is passed to the `ssh` command and thence to the remote shell.

Also, quotes don't nest, so the double-quotes in the command string don't do what you want -- the first of each pair is treated as a close-quote (matching whichever was before it), the section that's supposed to be quoted is then not in quotes at all, and the next double-quote starts a new quoted section. Since those are quotes *around* sections of the argument, the local shell removes them from the argument before passing it to `ssh`.

Between those two things, and assuming that `ntpd` is not running on the local computer, here's what actually gets passed to the remote computer as a command:

```
UP=       0;
if [  -ne 1 ];
then
        echo NTP is down.;
        sudo service ntpd start

else
        echo NTP Service is running.;
fi
```

The `[ -ne ]` expression is missing its left operand (remember, the quotes got removed), so `[` complains about that. I'm not sure why it thinks that's on line 1, as it looks like line 2 to me.

Solution 1: Use single-quotes around the whole command. Since it doesn't have any single-quotes in it nesting isn't an issue, and single-quotes suppress expansion of *everything*, so the various `$` expansions happen on the remote system.

Solution 2: Pass the commands as a (quoted) here-document instead of an argument (BTW, I also double-quoted `$EMAILMESSAGE` on general principles, and removed semicolons from the ends of lines where they're not needed):

```
ssh $USR@$host >> "$EMAILMESSAGE" <<'EOF'
UP=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep ntpd | wc -l);
if [ "$UP" -ne 1 ]
then
        echo "NTP is down."
        sudo service ntpd start

else
        echo "NTP Service is running."
fi
EOF
```

Solution 3: Skip the variable, and just use `grep -q` directly as the `if` test, and either escape the internal double-quotes or switch to single-quotes:

```
ssh $USR@$host "if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -q ntpd
then
        echo \"NTP is down.\"
        sudo service ntpd start

else
        echo \"NTP Service is running.\"
fi" >> "$EMAILMESSAGE"
```

Comment: Note that script expects the `ssh` command to set `UP` _locally_. Setting the `UP` variable on the remote system won't do any good.  The simple fix is to change `ssh ... "UP=$(...)"` into `UP=$( ssh ... )`.

Comment: One could even do `if ! ssh remote pgrep ntpd 2>/dev/null; then echo not running; fi`.

Comment: @Kusalananda After seeing your comment, I thought that might be possible... but it won't work; `service ntpd start` has to be run on the remote system, therefore all the testing and branching has to happen there as well.

Comment: Doesn't the `service` command have a `check` or `test` or whatever sub-command that tells you whether a service is running?  `if ! ssh remote service check ntpd; then echo not running; fi`

Comment: I see what you mean now, yes, the `service restart` has to run on the remote host. I think the testing done in the script is far too involved. Personally I would just have used `ssh remote 'pgrep ntpd || service start ntpd'` or something similar.

Comment: @Kusalananda That’d make it much simpler (assuming the remote system has `pgrep`). But if it were my script, I’d probably wind up making it more complicated, specifically to make it detect & report problems with either the `ssh` or `service` commands failing.